# passing a string variable as and input to loc accessor in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to pass a string variable (containing the parameter) to the .loc accessor but cannot get the syntax correct.

```
startenddate = "'2020-06':'2020-07'"
qf = cf.QuantFig(df = stock.data.loc[startenddate])
```

I get the error

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: '2020-06':'2020-07'
```

it works if I just plug in qf = cf.QuantFig(df = stock.data.loc['2020-06':'2020-07'])
but I want to convert this into a function and pass starenddate as a parameter that us used in the .loc.

Comment: I had to guess which `.loc` you are referring to; probably review the tags and see if you can clarify whether you are talking about NumPy, Pandas, or something else. Python itself does not have anything called `.loc`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by doing this:

```
start_date = '2020-06'
end_date = '2020-07'
data.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

You're passing a string into the .loc[] and then you expect it to match with the index.

Comment: Yeah that definitely works, Thanks.